# Whats the reason for " FBSDKLog: -1059155737 is not a valid FBSessionLoginBehavior. Ignoring open call." issue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

Note:- dont direct me to the similar question, i have read them and tried using newer API from parse and facebook. but problem still persists.

It would be really helpful if someone point me in the right direction as to what might be the possible cause for this bug.

Are parse sdk and Facebook sdk not compatible any more?

i read post on this site saying issue fixed with updating parse sdk,but i m still having same issue with parse sdk 1.2.15, 1.2.16 and facebook 3.9, 3.10.

NOTE:- i can get my name,user_id,email after each time I logout and login again. but every time i hit run it shows me the above mentioned bug.

here is my code:-

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:YES];
[PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook];

[FBRequestConnection
 startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
     if (!error) {
         userFBid = [(NSString *)[result objectForKey:@"id"] mutableCopy];
         NSLog(@"user fb id %@",userFBid);
         [self getNamePictureEmail];
     }
 }];
}

-(void)getNamePictureEmail
{
// GET NAME
NSString *nameURLString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@?fields=name",userFBid];

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:nameURLString];
NSData *data1=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
// json parsing to convert json response returned by fb into dictionary
NSDictionary *allDataDictionary1=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data1 options:0 error:nil];
fbUserName=[allDataDictionary1 objectForKey:@"name"];
NSLog(@"name %@",fbUserName);


[[FBRequest requestForMe]startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                      NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
                                                      NSError *error)
 {
     if (!error)
     {
         fbUSerEmail =  [user objectForKey:@"email"];
         NSLog(@"email %@",fbUSerEmail);
         [self registerUser];

     }
     else
     {
         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Facebook Sync Error" message:@"Please try login again" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
         [alert show];
     }
 }];
// GET PICTURE
NSString *pictureURLString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=normal",userFBid];
NSURL *PictureUrl1=[NSURL URLWithString:pictureURLString];
NSData *data3=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:PictureUrl1];
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code showing how you're opening a session? FBSessionLoginBehavior is an enum, and -1059155737 is not a valid element in the enum.

Comment: @MingLi updated my question with code.  thanx about the info, i m trying to find the reason for this. Hope this might help others too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally!

just deleted the framework path under **BUILD settings -->> Search Paths** deleted and added parse and facebook sdk again. It works all fine now.

hope it helps to many trying to figure it out